# Windows 8: jdk-8u25-windows-x64 will not run

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

I am wanting to run Eclipse as part of the ADT Bundle and must install the JDK first.  Since I am on a Windows 8.1 (basic, not Pro or Enterprise), I have downloaded jdk-8u25-windows-x64.exe.  When I try to run that installation file (whether as a local user or as administrator), nothing happens other than the UAC popup wanting my confirmation.  Just in case the installation process is transparent, I go ahead and run Eclipse but get a message that the JDK needs to be installed.  FYI, I have installed this JDK and the ADT Bundle a number of times successfully on various Win 7 platforms.  My searches regarding this problem have revealed nothing of a similar nature encountered by other people.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance for any help you might provide.

Comment: Have you tried an older java version on Windows 8.1? I'm just wondering whether you were able to get 7 installed? Maybe it's an issue with the 8 installer...

Comment: Thanks, munyui.  Yes, I have installed the 32-bit version (jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe), and that installation goes smoothly.  However, my ADT Bundle is the 64-bit version and understandably does not play well with the 32-bit JDK.  I am about to install the 32-bit 
ADT Bundle to see if that will do the trick, in spite of the OS and CPU being 64-bit models.

Comment: did you ever get the 64bit version working? I can't help but feel that I've seen this issue before, but I can't quite remember where.

Comment: No, did not get the 64 bit versions running; installed the 32 bit versions, and they run, but fail to create the R.java file.  Am giving up and will just remote into my Win7 machine at work.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try jre-7u67-windows-i586, 8 wasn't working good, and creating so many problemns. I just tried jre-7u67-windows-i586 and everything is fine now.